# Multiple Queries Database

Tags: php, mysql, database

I'm new to PHP but am in the process of creating a rather complex work experience database. At current there are two tables (employers, students) Now, I've used:

```
"SELECT * FROM employers ORDER BY Category, SubCategory, Name"
```

to generate a list of employers and their details. However, within this list I need to display which students are with which employers over the course of three weeks. I need to return a 'FirstName' value from 'students' if 'WeekOne' (also a column in 'students') = 'Name' (from 'employers')

Please help! If this is too garbled let me know - it's pretty difficult to explain.

Essentially, I want to generate a list that looks a bit like this:

> Company One, Address, Week One - Student, Week Two - Student, Week Three - Student
>
> Company Two, Address, Week One - Student, Week Two - Student, Week Three - Student
> etc

Comment: Can you post the columns available in each table? What I would suggest doing is selecting from the "students" table and joining in the needed data from the employers table.

Comment: @Steven What I want to get to is each employer with it's details and which student is there. Like this:
Employer,
Address,
Week One - Student,
Week Two - Student,
Week Three - Student

Answer (score 0):

Although it would be nice of you to show us your sql-tables, here is my idea of how you'll do it.

```
SELECT e.*, s.FirstName FROM employers AS e, students AS s
WHERE s.WeekOne = e.Name
OR s.WeekTwo = e.Name
OR s.WeekThree = e.Name
// etc
ORDER BY Category, SubCategory, Name
```

If I understood you correctly, this will help you fetch the data you need.

Comment: Sort of... What I need to get to is generate a complete list of employers that gives me the following info for each employer: (Employer Name)(Address)(Week 1 = Student)(Week 2 = Student)(Week 3 = Student)

Comment: Then you just add on `OR s.WeekTwo = e.Name` etc after the where, before the ORDER BY. I have edited my answer to show how it would be done.

Answer (score 0):

As i understand you want to get employers with their details.You can use such query by using join operation;

```
SELECT e.*, s.FirstName FROM students AS s
RIGHT JOIN employers AS e
ON s.WeekOne=e.Name
ORDER BY Category, SubCategory, Name
```

Comment: Sort of... What I need to get to is generate a complete list of employers that gives me the following info for each employer: (Employer Name)(Address)(Week 1 = Student)(Week 2 = Student)(Week 3 = Student)

Comment: Could you please also provide db structure?

Comment: For both tables? How do I do that? Sorry. Thanks.

Comment: it can be image output, if you are using a tool

Answer (score 0):

The SQL below would return the student's firstname and the employer's name, if the students table weekone column is equal to a 'Name' in the employers table.

```
SELECT students.FirstName, Employers.Name
FROM students
JOIN employers ON students.WeekOne = Employers.Name
```

I see, you want: *Employer, Address, Week One - Student, Week Two - Student, Week Three - Student*.

Try something like this:

```
SELECT e.name, e.address, student1.firstname AS 'Week One', student2.firstname AS 'Week Two', student3.firstname AS 'Week Three'
FROM employers AS e
JOIN students AS student1 ON e.name = student1.weekone
JOIN students AS student2 ON e.name = student2.weektwo
JOIN students AS student3 ON e.name = student3.weekthree
ORDER BY category, subcategory, e.name
```

Comment: Thanks for your help Terry - what do you mean by 'Student 1' etc? The 'students' table is a database of students with lots of individual information, including the columns 'Week One' 'Week Two' 'Week Three' which indicate which company they're at on the respective weeks.

Comment: Yep, student1 would be an alias for the student whose weekone field is equal to the employer's name. Same for student2, but his/her weekTwo field equals the employer's name. (I hope those sentences make a bit of sense)

Comment: This is going way over my head :( Is 'e' short form for employers - do I need to amend that?

Comment: Yeah, you can do <TABLENAME> AS <new-table-alias>. So FROM employers AS e (or as 'e') would make 'e' an alias for employers :). http://planet.mysql.com/entry/?id=19930

Comment: It's returning a blank page for me :S

Comment: Don't worry about it my friend. I'm clearly punching way above my weight here. Thanks for your help anyway.